# How can I improve this SQL query to be faster, today it takes a long time

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to improve the execution time of this sql, this is the code I am using at the moment.
For small tables it performs well, in the first table to participants, I have an average of 5000 entries. In the second, there are more than 60,000.
The code performs a search within the first table, filtering by ids, and groups the same ids as the second table, generating a single string.

```
SELECT `participant_name`,` participant cpf`, `participant fone`, GROUP_CONCAT (`idnumber` SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM `participants` to` p`
INNER JOIN` sorteio_18` as`s`
ON s.cpf = p.cpf_participant
GROUP BY `cpf_participante`
```

The structure of the first table is this

```
participant_id       INT  11
participant_name     VAR  100
cpf_participant      VAR  14
participant_birthday DATE 
participant_phone    VAR  16
qtd_numbers          INT  3
participant_email    VAR  100
status_transacao     INT  1
payment_form         INT  1
cep_participante     INT  8
lucky                INT  10
city                 VAR  100
uf                   VAR  2
neighborhood         VAR  100
address              VAR  100
number               INT  4 
purchase_date        DATE
order_number         VAR  15
transaction          VAR  100
code                 VAR  100
price_price          DEC  10,2
```

And the second table is

```
idnumber           INT 11
fullname           VAR 100
phone              VAR 16
email              VAR 100
cpf                VAR 14
cep                INT 8
participant_id     INT 11
neighborhood       VAR 100
address            VAR 100
active             INT 1
```

Can someone give me an idea of ​​how to improve the search time of this sql, because today it takes more than 10 minutes to generate the complete query.
Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: do you have indexes?

Comment: No, only primary keys

Comment: @Randy is correct, without indexes, MySQL must begin with the first row and then read through the entire table to find the relevant rows, this can be very costly depending on table size.

Comment: I'm not good with sql, I'm still learning, how could I do the indexes, is something I do while creating the table

Comment: @AndersonMoreira [CREATE INDEX](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-index/mysql-create-index/)

Comment: Thank you very much, I will implement now

Comment: NB a primary key is an index..your table definitions are incomplete.

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/ is a good introduction to indexes and how to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the query as written:

```
SELECT p.participant_name, p.`participant cpf`, p.`participant fone`, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(s.idnumber SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM participants p INNER JOIN`
     sorteio_18 s
     ON s.cpf = p.cpf_participante
GROUP BY p.cpf_participante;
```

I would suggest defining `cpf_partipante` as a primary key.  Then having an index on `sorteio_18(cpf, idnumber)`.

However, it would probably be faster to use:

```
select p.*,    -- whatever columns you want
       (select group_concat(s.idnumber separator ', ')
        from sorteio_18 s
        where s.cpf = p.cpf_participante
       ) as idnumbers
from participant p;
```

This only needs the index on `sorteio_18` described above.